# Transfer 10TB between s3 buckets and query it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, etl

I have huge amount of data i.e, in the scale of >10TB consisting of both structured and unstructured format.

Requirements are:

1. Transfer data from one s3 bucket to another
2. Query data in s3 bucket to download data to local

Which tool can I use to fulfil these requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the AWS CLI you can copy the contents of one bucket to another

```
aws s3 sync s3://[old-bucket-name] s3://[new-bucket-name]
```

The relevant documentation is [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Comment: is aws cli efficient for large datasets?

Comment: Note that this approach will stream the data to whatever server the aws CLI command is running on, and then back up to S3, so if you do this, you should do it from an EC2 server to prevent data egress charges.

Comment: @MarkB No, the `aws s3 sync` command sends `CopyObject` requests to S3. The data is copied between S3 buckets _without_ downloading and uploading to the computer running the AWS CLI command.

Comment: The downside of using the AWS CLI is that it must first retrieve the entire list of objects from the source bucket. If using `sync` it will also retrieve the list of objects from the destination bucket. This can take considerable time if there are a large number of objects. An alternate method is to use **S3 Batch Replication**. See: [Replicate Existing Objects with Amazon S3 Batch Replication | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-replicate-existing-objects-with-amazon-s3-batch-replication/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the clarification, I have apparently misunderstood that for years.

Comment: @MarkB You can test it by putting a LARGE file in S3 and performing a sync. You'll see it copies a lot faster than a download/upload would. It also sends many requests in parallel, so lots of data can move quickly!